# Unique Identifier for sent messages in good programming practice

Tags: c++, uniqueidentifier

A system send xml warning messages. To put the xml file together, a class was created so the warning could be generated before translating it to xml. Each message has to have an unique ID.
How unique? The IDs go from 3400 until 3500. If maximum is reached, the ID is reset.

```
#ifndef WARNINGMESSAGE_H
#define WARNINGMESSAGE_H
#include <ctime>

static unsigned int control_ID = 3399;
//Effect Codes:
const unsigned int TRAFFIC_FREE = 2;
//(...)
class WarningMessage{
 public:
  //setters
  void setActionID();

  //getters
  //(...)
 private:
  unsigned int actionID;    //to be controlled by control_ID
 };
#endif // WARNINGPARAMVEHICLE_H
```

And in the cpp file, when the id of a message needs to be setted, the following is executed:

```
#include "project/include/warningmessage.h"

//setters
void WarningParamVehicle::setActionID(){
 if(control_ID == 3500){
  control_ID = 3399;
 }
 control_ID++;
 actionID = control_ID;
}
```

Another detail that is important, the space in memory for this class message is given just once. Every time another message has to be sent, the instance is deleted and re-created as such:

```
void WarningDetector::createWarning(){
 delete currentWarningMessage;  // delete previous warning instance
 currentWarningMessage = new WarningMessage();
 (...)
}
```

and lastly, currentWarningMessage was declared in warning detector as a pointer:

```
WarningMessage* currentWarningMessage;
```

I can notice the bad programming practice in declaring the variable control_ID in the header file and outside of the class scope, however, given scenario coding like this look optimized. Is there a better way to solve this unique identifier problem seen here? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: "bad programming practice in declaring the variable control_ID in the header file and outside of the class scope"  --- so, how about putting the variable in the class scope?

Comment: If you have a WarningDetector class to the create the warnings, why don't you place the control_ID inside that class, and instead of having a setActionID, just pass the id in the constructor. new WarningMessage(nextId)

Comment: BTW, currently, you have one `control_ID` per translation unit including the header :/

Comment: @tenfour If I am not wrong, putting the variable in the class scope would make me lose count when new instance of  WarningMessage would be created.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto indeed your answer seems until now like the best option I have.

Comment: @Jarod42 very well noticed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good programming practice could include single responsibilities. For instance, setting the action id for the current message could be decoupled from deciding on the action id for the next message. This could enable consistent behavior when exceptions happen during the construction of a WarningMessage (if you get a chance to fix the cause of the exception you might want to try again to create the WarningMessage and expect the same actionId).

To address that and the other comments above you could for instance:

- make control_ID a private static member of WarningMessage (setActionID is currently a member of WarningMessage)
- remove the public setter setActionID and initialize actionID in the initialization list instead
- manage control_ID, last thing inside the constructor (in case there are exceptions)

In the header:

```
#ifndef WARNINGMESSAGE_H
#define WARNINGMESSAGE_H
#include <ctime>

//Effect Codes:
const unsigned int TRAFFIC_FREE = 2;
//(...)
class WarningMessage{
public:
  WarningMessage();
  //remove public setters if your use case doesn't require them
  //getters
  //(...)
private:
  // deconstructing control_ID
  static const unsigned ID_COUNT = 100;
  static const unsigned ID_START = 3400;
  static unsigned idOffset = 0;
  const unsigned int actionID;    //to be controlled by control_ID
};
#endif // WARNINGPARAMVEHICLE_H
```

And in the cpp file:

```
#include "project/include/warningmessage.h"

unsigned WarningMessage::idOffset = 0;

WarningMessage::WarningMessage()
: actionId(ID_START + idOffset) /* ... */
{
    // increment idOffset only when you are sure that it is safe
    ++idOffset;
    idOffset %= ID_COUNT;
}
```

Note that this is not going to work in a multi-threaded environment, but that doesn't seem to be your concern at the moment

Comment: Wouldn't I lose count of the id (idOffset would be restarted to 0) when a new instance of WarningMessage is created? Curerntly every new message comes with a new instance of WarningMessage.
You are right, multi-threads are not my concern right now. Thanks you the help.

Comment: @okaitt no idOffset would not be restarted to 0 when you create a new instance. [Static members variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm) are shared by all objects in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 constants `IDMIN = 3499` and `IDMAX = 3500` to avoid having magic numbers in an implementation file. Those constants should be static const members of class `WarningMessage`.

I would set `control_ID` as a static variable in the method `WarningParamVehicle::setActionID` (isn't it `WarningMessage::setActionID` ?). It would then give :

```
class WarningMessage{
 public:
  static const int IDMIN = 3499;
  static const int IDMAX = 3500;
  //setters
  void setActionID();
  ...
```

and later in implementation :

```
void WarningParamVehicle::setActionID(){
 static int control_ID = WarningMessage::IDMIN;

 if(control_ID == IDMAX){
  control_ID = IDMIN;
 }
 control_ID++;
 actionID = control_ID;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I lose count of the id when a new instance of WarningMessage is created? Curerntly every new message comes with a new instance of WarningMessage. Thanks for your help.